# Python 3.7 connecting to HSQLDB on MAC

Tags: java, python, r, hsqldb

Trying to connect to a HSQLDB Java database using python 3.7, jaydebeapi, and jpype. I tried the following

```py
import jaydebeapi

UserName = "SA"
Password = ""
Java_Class = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
HSQL_Driver_Path = "/Hsqldb/driver/hsqldb.jar"
Database = "jdbc:hsqldb:/Hsqldb/database/OneDatabase"
jaydebeapi.connect(Java_Class,Database,[UserName,Password],jars=HSQL_Driver_Path)
```

and it resulted in the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found

google states that this is a classpath error and I need to add a class path to fix.

edit: Details of setup: Mac, anaconda, python 3.7

I tried something similar in R using the `RJDBC` library and was able to connect just fine.

```
PathDriver = "/Hsqldb/driver/hsqldb.jar"
JDBCDriver = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
drv <- JDBC(JDBCDriver,PathDriver)

# Connect to Database
DatabaseP <- "jdbc:hsqldb:file:////Hsqldb/database/OneDatabase"
Con <- dbConnect(drv,DatabaseP,"SA","")
```

edit: Details of setup: Mac, R, Rstudio

I separated R from Anaconda as Anaconda was blocking many of the libraries I wanted to use.

This is probably apples to oranges, but why does python need a classpath set when R performs the function just fine? and how does one set a class path for HSQLDB for python?

Answer (score 0):

When starting JPype it either takes the classpath from the environment variable `CLASS_PATH` or from a manually specified classpath defined using the `jpype.startJVM(classpath="...")` command.  This command is likely part of the jaydebeapi api if you don't have to call it directly from JPype.

I assume that R defines its own classpath internally so there may just be differences in the what is being seen from the JVM.  This could include a different JVM is being selected, the classpath including different locations, or in some cases if the driver has a native portion such as MS SQLServer the library path may also not be correct. In order for the JDBC driver to load all piece need to be found including the jar, support jars and native shared libraries.  If all else fails manually try to load the java class using `Class.forname`. It may provide you with further diagnostics as to which piece is missing.